# Third party Exe not running on windows server 2008 R2 from asp.net but running fine manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, exe, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework-version

[Event 1026 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLeu.png)  [Event 1000 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9dgT.png) I have a third party exe which I am trying to run from my asp.net application.It is running fine in my local machine but not on windows server 2008 R2. It is throwing 3 errors every time I tried running from the application with event ids 1000,1022 and 1026.It is running fine when I run manually.I am getting two .Net runtime errors and one Application Error. The errors are not pointing to any specific line or code. My exe is not even initiated to run.

I get some vague "Faulting Module Name : C:/windows/sysWOW64/kernelbase.dll" error.

My application consists of classic asp pages too. .Net application was pointing to framework 3.5. As this third party exe points to 4.0, I upgraded my existing application to 4.7.1.

I created another independent web application pointing to 4.7.1 and it is able to run the said exe without any issues on the same server.But, my existing application is throwing error.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: How are you calling the *.exe in your code?

Comment: What does the 3rd party developer say about the error?

Comment: App Pool Permissions? App Pool doesn't have a profile and the exe needs a profile?

Comment: If you're running the executable as its own, separate process, there is no need at all to match .NET Framework versions between your web site and the application (since they can't share it anyway), and any mismatch in versions is likely a red herring.

Comment: @ChrFin, I am calling the exe using Process.Start().

Comment: @vdwwd, 3rd Party developed it long back and client do not want to go back to them due to cost issues.

Comment: @Matt, Can you please eloborate.

Comment: @jeron Mostert, when running it as its own process, then there are no issues. But, again I cant run this from a console application but only as a web app. It runs perfectly. In this case I need to host another website and then run from the existing.This is last option. Yes there is no need of matching frameworks. The requirement is to run from the existing application.

Comment: Although it's possible to do this, there are lots of [dangers](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) to doing it. You would be better off using a library such as [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Both of these libraries have been built to handle these pitfalls.

Comment: IIS runs your app in something called an AppPool, this out of the box has a user assigned with reduced access to the system to reduce the effect if your server is hacked through bad code, you can change this user to a real user which might have enough permissions to run the exe, I don't know if this is what is causing your issues but it's a possibility.

Comment: @Matt, this exe is not configured as another application to run under another AppPool. It is residing in a folder in the web application and I am trying to execute this from same application. I tried giving permissions to all the users as well as administrators on the server for the folders which deal with exe and application. I tried writing another console which runs my exe and my web application runs this console app. But, still it resulted in same error. I edited the question and attached error screenshots.

Comment: Has anyone faced this issue before and found a solution? Please let me know.